# First iOS app - Should I use RubyMotion or Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rubymotion

I am about to start building my first iOS app.  I have no prior programming experience other than basic HTML and CSS and an understanding of OOP and MVC concepts.  What are your thoughts on my writing the app in RubyMotion or Objective-C?

I understand that the difficulty of building a native iOS app for the first time has less to do with learning the Objective-C syntax and more to do with learning CocoaTouch.

I read this synopsis - http://aelogica.com/development/rubymotion-review/ - and felt it was complete, but I wanted to ask the community to see if anyone had a different opinion.

This article was also pretty helpful - http://merbist.com/2012/05/04/macruby-on-ios-rubymotion-review/

Thank you!

Comment: I should also mention that the app is not a game (re: any performance follow-up comments on going the native route).  It is an app where people could post photos and send messages to each other.

Comment: This question goes against the FAQ.  There is no correct answer to this question, only discussions and arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mac you will probably be using xcode to develop apps using Objective-C,  i use xcode a lot and it is easy to learn how to use.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the basics of c language.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much time available for the building application and the gadgets available.Objective C with xcode is easy .But you need an mac for it.but You have knowledge on HTML and CSS makes me say you go for HTML based mobile application devolopment,such as phonegap,sencha ect.